# Understanding "quitter des yeux son adversaire"

Tags: syntaxe

The question is on the highlighted phrase in this excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus.  In it, Raymond has caught up with a man who, earlier in the morning, had given him knife wounds on his mouth and arm.

> Pendant tout ce temps, il n’y a plus eu que le soleil et ce silence, avec le petit bruit de la source et les trois notes. Puis Raymond a porté la main à sa poche revolver, mais l’autre n’a pas bougé et ils se regardaient toujours. J’ai remarqué que celui qui jouait de la flûte avait les doigts des pieds très écartés. Mais sans **quitter des yeux son adversaire,** Raymond m’a demandé : « Je le descends ? » J’ai pensé que si je disais non il s’exciterait tout seul et tirerait certainement. Je lui ai seulement dit : « Il ne t’a pas encore parlé. Ça ferait vilain de tirer comme ça. »

Which of the following reading is right?  (Or if neither, please tell me how to read it correctly.)

Reading 1

- *des* is a contraction of *de les*.
- *quitter des yeux* forms a single verb phrase, somewhat on the model of English expressions like *fleet of foot* or *hard of hearing*.
- *son adversaire* is a direct object (in the accusative so-to-speak).

Reading 2

- *des* is an indefinite article.
- *des yeux* is a direct object.
- *son adversaire* is an indirect object or in the dative.

Because I never (in my limited experience) saw a French noun standing alone (without a preposition) serving as a dative, I am betting on 1.

If 1 is right, please give me some other verb phases that look like *quitter des yeux*.

Comment: Do not change the title of your question because you can use the expression *quitter des yeux* without *sans*. [Here for example](http://www.lnc.nc/photo/lindsay-gavin-a-quitte-des-yeux-son-adversaire-une-erreur-qui-va-lui-etre-fatale) it is used as a title of a newspaper article.

Comment: So, in french you *take somebody off your eyes*, instead of *taking your eyes off somebody*. You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more like "Reading 1" and might be translated:

> but without taking his eyes off his foe

*Quitter des yeux* is indeed a verbal phrase here, meaning "loosing eye contact", almost always used in negative sentences but sometimes not:

*Je l'ai quitté des yeux deux secondes et il s'est échappé !*

> I stopped watching him for a couple of seconds and he escaped!

Here are other similar verbal phrases:

> *Je ne l'ai pas quitté d'une semelle pendant toute la journée.* -> to constantly stay close to someone, to closely follow
>
> *Je l'ai perdu de vue depuis longtemps.* -> to lose contact with someone
>
> *J'en ai gardé sous le pied.* -> to keep a bit back

Answer (score 1):

- quitter ⇒ verbe
- des ⇒ préposition
- yeux ⇒ nom
- des yeux ⇒ complément prépositionnel
- son ⇒ adjectif possessif
- adversaire ⇒ nom
- son adversaire ⇒ complément d'objet direct.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP did not ask the meaning of the phrase but whether or not it is grammatically correct. His first *reading* is correct, but I detailed it since he's curious about the grammatical side of the sentence, nothing else. My grammatical analysis is correct and precise

Comment: I don't see a reason for downvoting either.  I have upvoted though I am selecting another answer for expressly affirming "reading 1" in the main body of the answer.

Comment: @Catomic Yes, as I said through my comment: your *reading 1* is correct, I just detailed further the grammar

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't use it without "sans":

> **sans** quitter des yeux

It's always used this way, in a negative.

> ne pas quitter quelque chose, quelqu'un des yeux

Think of

> can't take my eyes off you

It doesn't make any sense if you read it literally too!

Comment: Your answer is wrong because we use that expression without *sans*. See my comment below the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, as I already wrote in my answer, *Quitter des yeux* might be used in a positive sentence, i.e. without *sans*.