# Understanding "haletait de toute la respiration rapide et étouffée de ses petites vagues."

Tags: syntaxe

I am trying to understand the syntactic structure of the second sentence of this excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus.

> C’était le même éclatement rouge. **Sur le sable, la mer haletait de toute la respiration rapide et étouffée de ses petites vagues.**

**Question**

Am I right to understand it this way?

- *de ses petites vagues* modifies *respiration*.
- *de toute la respiration* complements *haletait* (in much the same way *des yeux* complements *quitter* in *quitter des yeux son adversaire* as I learned in this [other post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/understanding-quitter-des-yeux-son-adversaire)).

**Background**

I am not asking what I should imagine.  I want to understand how the sentence works.  For instance, I want to make sure that *de ses petites vagues* does not connect to *haletait* or *étouffée* somehow.

This German translation seems to understand the French original the same way as set out above.

> Es war dieselbe rote Explosion. Auf dem Sand hechelte das Meer mit den schnellen, erstickten Atemzügen seiner kleinen Wellen.

This English translation decided to get rid of *respiration.*

> There was the same dazzling red glare. The sea gasped for air with each shallow, stifled little wave that broke on the sand.

Comment: Apart from the non-strict parallel with *quitter des yeux*, you got it right on the nose.

Comment: The German translation is indeed much closer to the original French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Décomposition:**

- la mer haletait
- la mer haletait *de quelle manière / comment ?*
- la mer haletait *par l'effet de ses petites vagues*

Quel effet ?

toute la respiration rapide et étouffée de ses petites vagues

=> de manière simplifiée: la respiration de ses vagues.

**rapide et étouffée** : complémentent respiration

**petites vagues** est l'acteur de respiration: on pourrait dire: ses petites vagues respirent.

**Quitter des yeux** est un peu différent: on ne peut pas enlever *des yeux* sans modifier le sens de *quitter*.