# Understanding "laisser pleuvoir du feu"

Tags: syntaxe, constructions-causatives

The question is on this sentence from L'Étranger by Camus.  It is describing a scorching summer sky.

> Il m'a semblé que le ciel s'ouvrait sur toute son étendue pour **laisser pleuvoir du feu.**

Which way of understanding *du feu* is correct?

1. *du* is a partitive article.  *du feu* is the subject of *pleuvoir*, i.e. it is what rains.  *laisser pleuvoir du feu* means "letting fire rain."
2. *du* is a partitive article.  *du feu* is the object of *pleuvoir*, which is a transitive verb here; i.e. *du feu* is what gets poured. *laisser pleuvoir du feu* means "allowing the pouring of fire" or "allowing fire to be poured." We don't find out who or what is doing the pouring.
3. *du* is a contraction of *de le*. *du feu* is a prepositional complement of *pleuvoir* and describes the manner of raining or pouring.  (*de feu* can be compared to *de toute la respiration* in [this other post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/understanding-haletait-de-toute-la-respiration-rapide-et-%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e-de-ses-petite) or to "with love" in "loving someone with the love of a brother.")

A related question would be:  how one says, "Then God let it rain."  Can we say *Alors le Dieu le laisser pleuvoir*?

Answer (score 2):

### Laisser pleuvoir du feu.

I think it fits most with 2 and 3. Here, "laisser pleuvoir du feu" means there will be a rain made of fire, in an apocalyptic meaning.
**du feu** is a *COD* (*Complément d'Objet Direct*), beacause you can ask

> Laisser pleuvoir quoi ? Du feu

You will find the same structure in those sentences:

> pour laisser passer le train
>   pour laisser couler de l'eau

You use "**du**" because "water" and "fire" are **not countable**.
Whereas you use "**le**" because a train is **countable**.
So "du" has the meaning of "some" here (maybe you could say "let rain some fire" ?)

### Then God let it rain

You would say one of those:

> Alors Dieu laissa pleuvoir (a bit odd)
>   Alors Dieu laissa la pluie tomber

You only use "le Dieu" if you want to stress the fact there is only **1** God. Otherwise, "Dieu" is a proper name.

Comment: Thanks. Though you said "2 and 3" I think the rest of your answer points to 2 alone. Also please see the other answer (by guillaume girod-vitouchkina), which says 1. Without some reconciliation between the two answers, I could only conclude that the expression admits of both readings. It wouldn't be a strange outcome to me. "Fire's downpour" would be similarly ambiguous.

Comment: I don't know what the potential “acted upon” is called in causative constructions, but *du feu* is here used as a COD in the infinitive clause. However, your question does not help to find this out; your reasoning is wrong. Think of this sentence: *Il laisse tomber des cailloux*. *Des cailloux* could only be subject of *tomber*, but the question is also “Laisser tomber quoi ?”. This means that native speakers cannot even rely on their knowledge of this question to distinguish between an “acted upon” and a COD of the infinitive clause.

Answer (score 0):

The good meaning is your number 1.

**Du is a partitive article.**

One can also say: *la neige*, or *de la neige*, *du feu*, or *le feu*, ...

**Du feu is subject of pleuvoir.**

Laisser is a *semi-auxiliaire* (like *faire*, *voir*, *regarder*, *entendre*, *sentir* )

Le bon usage 14, 821 f.

See also: http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic11075-faire-infinitif-expose.html

**I propose two meanings for 'Then God let it rain':**

- *Alors Dieu laissa pleuvoir*.
- *Alors Dieu fit en sorte qu'il pleuve* or *qu'il plût*, or *Dieu fit qu'il pleuve* / *qu'il plût*, or *Dieu fit pleuvoir*.

More, this is stylistic because fire doesn't rain, normally !

Comment: Please see the other answer (by Random), which says 2. Without some reconciliation between the two answers, I could only conclude that the expression admits of both readings. Also, thanks for mentioning Le Bon Usage.  Is there any free online access to it?  What I found (lebonusage.com) seems to be a paid site.

Comment: @Catomic Difficile de faire mieux que le [_snippet view_](https://books.google.com/books?id=gu0cAQAAIAAJ&dq=editions:HMHBhyhND3QC&lr=&hl=fr&redir_esc=y) (d'une version antérieure), complètement inadéquat considérant la nature de l’œuvre. Parfois on en retrouve des extraits pertinents au [_Guichet du savoir_](http://guichetdusavoir.org/index.php)...

Comment: @Catomic   It is not a COD. I put another link.

Comment: One can say *il pleut des chats*. Technically, *des chats* is an object in this sentence. **Des chats pleuvent* is not possible. Similarly *du feu* is necessarily the object of *pleuvoir*. However, the causative construction does not enforce that. For example *laisser peindre Paul* is ambigous.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez . Sorry but no. In: Il pleut, il neige, il tombe, il coule, il entre, il apparaît, il surgit, ... des chats, des fantômes, ... : it is impersonal form. Real subject is chats. chats can never be COD, because these verbs dont have COD. "Des chats pleuvent" is possible.